Python multiprocessing causes OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
Edit: I'm using pypy.
I'm trying to parallelize my python script by using a process Pool of 4 workers from the multiprocessing module. This error seems to suggest that too many pipes are opening, but I fail to see how this is the case, given that I only spawn 4 workers.
This is the function that executes the spawns the Pool:
def do_learning_experiments(model, alphabet, correct_size, prot):
    """
    Perform the learning experiments for the given model and alphabet.

    Args:
        model: model to learn
        alphabet: input alphabet
        correct_size: correct size of the model
    """
    # create a copy of the SUL for each oracle
    suls = [AutomatonSUL(model) for _ in range(NUM_ORACLES)]
    wpr = WALKS_PER_ROUND[prot]
    wl = WALK_LEN[prot]
    # initialize the oracles
    eq_oracles = [StochasticRandom(alphabet, suls[0], wpr, wl),
                  StochasticLinear(alphabet, suls[1], wpr, wl),
                  StochasticSquare(alphabet, suls[2], wpr, wl),
                  StochasticExponential(alphabet, suls[3], wpr, wl)]
    # create the arguments for eache oracle's task
    tasks = [(alphabet, sul, oracle, correct_size, i)
             for i, (sul, oracle) in enumerate(zip(suls, eq_oracles))]
    with mp.Pool(processes=mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
        results = pool.starmap(process_oracle, tasks)

    return results

I run this function multiple times, inside a for loop, in order to average out the measurements, like this:
for trial in range(TIMES):
    results = do_learning_experiments(model, alphabet, correct_size, prot)

What I have noticed is that, when I set TIMES=1 or TIMES=10 for example, this error does not occur. However, when I set TIMES=30 (which is what I want), the error occurs.
This leads me to believe that the processes are not properly closed, but I don't see more than 5 python processes alive at any moment in the system monitor.
How can I fix this or at least debug it?

In my case, the problem was solved by manually calling the garbage collector using gc.collect() after the with block.
I believe this does not agree with the multiprocessing documentation. There, it is suggested that a context manager is sufficient to properly handle the resources and that we should not rely on the garbage collector to do it.
Warning

multiprocessing.pool objects have internal resources that need to be properly 
managed (like any other resource) by using the pool as a context manager or by
 calling close() and terminate() manually. Failure to do this can lead to the
 process hanging on finalization.

Note that it is not correct to rely on the garbage collector to destroy the
 pool as CPython does not assure that the finalizer of the pool will be called
 (see object.__del__() for more information).

